# Is there a way to make GPUImageView output existing CMSampleBuffer?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, gpuimage

I want to use `GPUImageView` to output `CMSampleBuffer` which I receive from my `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`. So, basically, I don't want GPUImage framework to manage `AVCaptureSession` itself, I just want it to draw what I'd pass to it. Still I can't see any obvious and easy way to do that. Is it even possible?

Comment: Seems like you want to make some manipulation (filtering) on that CMSampleBuffer before you display it, am I right?

Comment: @krafter not really. I had OpenGL drawing code which rendered CMSampleBuffer into GLKView, but I was experiencing a crash that I couldn't find a reason for, so I just wanted to replace GLKView with GPUImageView without changing the surrounding code.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you can do, fast and simple:

1.Set up your GPUImage with GPUImageView to output the frames as usual. Just like they do it in examples.

2. Dive into **GPUImageVideoCamera** class. Add a delegate there. Like one:

   @protocol GPUImageVideoCameraDelegate 
   @optional

   - (void)videoCameraCaptureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection;
     @end
3. Go to GPUImageVideoCamera.m, find the: **- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection** method.
4. Add your delegate call in there.

**if (self.delegate) {
    [self.delegate videoCameraCaptureOutput:captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer fromConnection:connection];
}**

5. Set your controller/class/whatever as delegate, `videoCamera.delegate = self;`
6. Use the delegate method in your class and do whatever you want with the **CMSampleBufferRef**.

Make sure you work with **CMSampleBufferRef** "in-place", meaning - do not copy it into CPU memory if you wish to avoid using relatively slow CPU versus faster GPU.

From there you can set any image into **CMSampleBufferRef**.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but I was wondering whether there is already a built-in way to do that, without changing the code of the library. Anyway, I refactored my code so that I don't have to deal with sample buffer myself, and it solved my problem.